# React Native keeping date as state in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am still getting familiar with React Native, so I simply want my class component Date to return a Text component which displays the current month. However I am confused how to essentially incorporate the following code into my class component:

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
```

So that I can use month in my Text tag:

```
class Date extends Component {
   state = {month: /*new Date().getMonth() ???*/}

   render(props) {
     return (
       <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}> Budget for {month} </Text>
     );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try .toString() as {month.toString()} as Date is an object. You can use moment or date-fns to convert it into a more user-friendly format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Date extends Component {
   state = {month:''}

   componentDidMount(){
     const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
     this.setState({ month }); 

   }

   render(props) {
     return (
       <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}> Budget for {this.state.month} </Text>
     );
    }
}
```